# Internal error. java.lang.RuntimeException: com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: Fatal error initializing

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-3.1.3

I find many solution but no one work then i uninstall android studio and download the lastest version and again install but i get this error again. Please tell me the solution of this problem.
[Error in android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSwTP.png)

Answer (score 0):

Solved this problem.

I empty the plugins at the directory of C:\Users....AndroidStudio\config\plugins and it work normally.

Answer (score 0):

My problem for this on Linux was file permissions as I changed the default ones after extracting the archive. The default permissions are `rwx------` for all files and directories. I changed it to `rw-r--r--` (644) for all files and `rwxr-x-r-x` (755) for directories. This is where I got this error. The fix for me was making `*.sh` and `*.so` files executable. So

```
cd /path/to/IntelliJ
find . -type f -name *.sh -exec chmod 755 '{}' ';'
find . -type f -name *.so -exec chmod 755 '{}' ';'
cd bin
./idea.sh
```

Works fine for me now.

Edit: Actually there was 1 extra step. The binary files inside of the JRE folder need to be executable as well.

```
cd /path/to/IntelliJ
find jre64/bin/ -type f -exec chmod 755 '{}' ';'
```